# why does relative layout position all pics in midscreen

Tags: android-layout

i am trying to control the position of an image on an activity within relative view.
but no matter what i do. the pic always shows up in the middle of the screen.

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"

        android:src="@drawable/hp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

even though i tried align and everything i could think of.

Comment: Please provide the full XML layout resource and name what "everything you could think of" includes.

Comment: i put everything i could think of within the imageView. perhaps im just doing something wrong and u control the imageview from the relative layout? there most b a simple way to align the picture to top of screen....

Comment: Is that your whole XML file? It is malformed; wonders me that Android is not complaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

Two stars. One relative to the parent (bound to top-left) and one relative to the first star (bound top-left to the first one - see `layout_below` and `layout_toRightOf`).

[image: Example rendered]

**Source**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

</RelativeLayout>
```